# Is there a function to set the section title of the tableview so that the title would not be uppercase?

Tags: ios, tableview

I created a tableview and set the section title. But the title is uppercase and I cannot find a way to make the title of the section normal.
I know we can create a label to avoid the setting which makes the title capital but I wonder if there is a system method to deal with this problem.

Here is the old code:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return @"The Content";
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *headerView = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;
    headerView.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    headerView.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
}
```

And thanks to Alok's answer,thought his solution is not what I want. But it remind me that we can actually edit the content in `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section` so that the capitalization problem can be solved.

Here is the new code:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return @"The Content";
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *headerView = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;
    headerView.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    headerView.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    headerView.textLabel.text = @"The Content";
}
```

What we need is to set the content of the tableview section again in `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section` and the setting in `- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` should be still.

Comment: Can you show your attempt? how your setting the text to section title? Is your section is custom ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But the title is uppercase and I cannot find a way to make the title of the section normal.

> Yes that is by design.

**Solution:**

Implement below delegate method & it should solve your problem.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    let titleView = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    titleView.textLabel?.text =  titleView.textLabel?.text?.capitalized
}
```

Comment: The problem I faced is that the title of the section becomes capitalized and you capitalize it again LOL. But still, you remind me that I can deal the problem in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int)`. I set the style of the title by this but didn't think about setting the content again in this function. Whatever, thank you.

Comment: I only think about how to cancel the default setting of capitalization but setting the content is still a good way for it.